# Simple.Data: How do you insert new row into a table containing only a identity column?

Tags: simple.data

If you have a table containing only one column, and that column has an identity specification. How do you write the insert statement using simple.data? I've tried both the "DataBase.Table.Insert()" approach and the "expando with no properties approach"; neither work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.Table.Insert(columnName: null);
```

should work.